# What's wrong with my code? self.c.execute("DELETE from books WHERE book_name="+str(delBooks))

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

In self.c.execute("DELETE from books WHERE book_name="+str(delBooks)) I want to call the variable delBooks from the method deleteBooks but it is not working? That is PyQt5 and my database I use is sqlite3.

```
class DeleteDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeleteDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.QBtn = QPushButton()
        self.QBtn.setText("Delete Book")

        self.setWindowTitle("Delete Book")
        self.setFixedWidth(300)
        self.setFixedHeight(100)
        self.QBtn.clicked.connect(self.deleteBooks)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.deleteinput = QLineEdit()
        self.deleteinput.setPlaceholderText("Book Name")
        layout.addWidget(self.deleteinput)
        layout.addWidget(self.QBtn)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def deleteBooks(self):

        delBooks = ""
        delBooks = self.deleteinput.text()
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
            self.c = self.conn.cursor()
            self.c.execute("DELETE from books WHERE book_name="+str(delBooks))
            self.conn.commit()
            self.c.close()
            self.conn.close()
            QMessageBox.information(QMessageBox(),'Successful','Deleted From Table Successful')
            self.close()
        except Exception:
            QMessageBox.warning(QMessageBox(), 'Error', 'Could not Delete that book from database.')
```

Comment: Please describe the error. On the first look I guess it's missing quotes around the name. BTW there is an SQL injection vulnerability in your code. A proper SQL parameter substitution will probably fix both problems. But as I said proper problem description would be helpful.

Comment: Remove the `try/except` statements, or print the `Exception` to get the error.

Comment: My code is actually 300 plus I just only post the code where I'm having problem, thank you for your answer I will try that.

Comment: When I remove the try/except statements this is the erro shows,        self.c.execute("DELETE from books WHERE book_name="+str(delBooks))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Chemistry

Comment: Can you help me what's the problem with that?